# smbclient not able to connect to after upgrade to RHEL7

Tags: linux, rhel, samba, smbclient

```
smbclient //ERERYMJF/pwiwerp_Informatica -U 'PWI.kpp.com\a121212'
```

Above command was working fine before and not working on RHEL7.  I am getting below error.

```
SPNEGO(gse_krb5) NEG_TOKEN_INIT failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
```

***samba.conf***

```
[global]
        client use spnego = no
        client ntlmv2 auth = yes

        workgroup = SAMBA
        security = user

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw



[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        browseable = No
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/tmp
        printable = Yes
        create mask = 0600
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
        write list = @printadmin root
        force group = @printadmin
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775
```

We are using Version 4.7.1.

Comment: I suspect this may be an SMB v1 vs SMB v2/v3 issue. Does the server `ERERYMJF` support SMB v2/v3? (If not, why not? SMB v1 is obsolete.)

Comment: I just have file system access to the remote windows server. Is there a way to get SMB version of remote host?

Comment: I used the completed name of the sever - ERERYMJF - i.e. ERERYMJF.xyz.com and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used completed name of the server - ERERYMJF - i.e. ERERYMJF.xyz.com and it worked!

```
smbclient //**ERERYMJF.xyz.com**/pwiwerp_Informatica -U 'PWI.kpp.com\a121212'
```

As @roaima mentioned it is not a good solution and throws away the security around samba. However, this seems to be the only solution working for me as off now.

Answer (score 0):

I found this AU Q&A titled: [Ubuntu 17.10 to access Windows Files Shares within workplace IT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008992/ubuntu-17-10-to-access-windows-files-shares-within-workplace-it)

```
SPNEGO(gse_krb5) NEG_TOKEN_INIT failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
```

A workaround was shown that may work for you as well:

```
$ cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
...
client use spnego = no
client ntlmv2 auth = no
workgroup = WINWIRKGRP
...
```

Comment: I tried this. Did not work..

Comment: I fixed it with a minor change. I used the completed name of the sever - ERERYMJF - i.e. ERERYMJF.xyz.com and it worked!

Comment: @Koshur - that terrific, be sure to mark your answer as accepted so others know it's resolved.

Comment: This is a really bad solution. What you're doing is telling Samba to throw away much of the security wrapping and revert to really obsolete authentication.

Comment: @roaima - agreed and understood. It's what's also shown in many of the upstream bugs raised against these types of issues, so it seems the only options for these issues ATM.

Comment: I've also seen them. The biggest problem I encounter is SMB v1 from network scanner/printers. I find I need to permit SMB v1 and the rest follows, rather then explicitly turning it all off.